# Can ReLU Activation Functions create Non-Convex Loss Functions in Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, loss-functions

**Can ReLU Activation Functions create Non-Convex Loss Functions in Neural Networks?**

From another question on Stackoverflow (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287716/the-composition-of-two-convex-functions-is-convex/287725), I learned that the composition of two convex functions will always be convex:

We want to prove that for $x, y \in \Omega$, $(g \circ f)\left(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y\right) \le \lambda (g \circ f)(x) + (1 - \lambda)(g \circ f)(y)$.

We have:
\begin{align}
(g \circ f)\left(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y\right) &= g\left(f\left(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y\right)\right) \\
&\le g\left(\lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda) f(y)\right) & \text{(} f \text{ convex and } g \text{ nondecreasing)} \\
&\le \lambda g(f(x)) + (1 - \lambda)g(f(y)) & \text{(} g \text{ convex)} \\
&= \lambda (g \circ f)(x) + (1 - \lambda)(g \circ f)(y)
\end{align}

**My Question:** Take a Neural Network in which all Activation Functions are ReLU. We know that the ReLU function is a convex function - we also know that the general structure of Neural Networks are based on multiple compositions of Activation Functions.

Thus, when we put these two logical arguments together : **How is it possible for the Loss Function of some Neural Network (where all activation functions are ReLU) to be Non-Convex - when compositions of Convex Functions are necessarily Convex?**

Can someone please explain this?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, NNs admit negative weights. How does your analysis of convexity change if you reverse the sign of just one of $f$ or $g$?

Comment: @ Sycorax: Thank you for your reply! Negative weights would not change the sign of the ReLU function. If you change the sign of "f" or "g", they will become concave. I am not sure if a composition of a concave and a convex function has the ability to produce a non-convex function?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972469/what-is-composition-of-convex-and-concave-function

Comment: Seems like you've found your answer.

Comment: @ Syrorax : Unfortunately, it is still not clear to me. I tried to draw some simple 2 layered neural networks, find the Hessian Matrix for these neural networks, and use online matrix solvers to see some specific examples where its possible to come across a negative eigen value ... but these matrices become so big  (e.g. 20 x 20) and it becomes very easy to make mistakes.